# Mezzanine mobile site menu remove

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, mezzanine, mobile-devices

I use Mezzanine with responsive bootstrap. When I visit the site for the first time with a mobile device I get the default Mezzanine menu where it says: This is the mobile homepage... View Full Site. So if I want to continue I need to click the View Full Site button and than I get my website. How can I get rid of this Mezzanine Menu since I don't need it. I want users to go directly to my website..

[image: mobile screenshot]

PS: this menu only appears the first time in a browser than once clicking View Full Site it does not appear anymore. In my header I have:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing "mezzanine.mobile" from the `INSTALLED_APPS` setting in your settings.py module.

http://mezzanine.jupo.org/docs/device-handling.html#mobile-theme